# Python multiprocessing producing unstable results

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Can anyone help me understand why this simple example of trying to speed up a for loop using python's `multiprocessing` module produces unstable results? I use a `Manager.List` to store the values from the child processes.

Clearly I'm doing at least one thing wrong. What would be the correct way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Manager


def run_parallel(x_val, result):

    val = np.arctan(x_val)

    result.append(val)


def my_func(x_array, parallel=False):

    if not parallel:
        result = []
        for k in x_array:
            result.append(np.arctan(k))

        return result

    else:
        manager = Manager()
        m_result = manager.list()

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
        pool.map(partial(run_parallel, result=m_result), x_array)

        return list(m_result)


test_x = np.linspace(0.1,1,50)
serial = my_func(test_x,parallel=False)
parallel = my_func(test_x,parallel=True)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(test_x, serial, label='serial')
plt.plot(test_x,parallel, label='parallel')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

The output I'm getting looks like this

[image: this]

and it looks different every time this runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some print functions and it turned out that the order of elements from x_array is arbitrary... That's why it looks so weird. I think you should keep argument and value of arctan pairs and then order it by argument value

**EDIT**

I read more and it turned out that `map` **returns** values in order... This works as you wanted:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Manager


def run_parallel(x_val, result):

    val = np.arctan(x_val)
    return val


def my_func(x_array, parallel=False):
    if not parallel:
        result = []
        for k in x_array:
            result.append(np.arctan(k))

        return result

    else:
        manager = Manager()
        m_result = manager.list()

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
        x = pool.map(partial(run_parallel, result=m_result), x_array)
        return list(x)


test_x = np.linspace(0.1,1,50)
parallel = my_func(test_x,parallel=True)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(test_x,parallel, label='parallel')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: ...which makes the `manager` object totally superfluous. Therefore it should be removed. Further, `pool.map` (as opposed to the normal `map`) already returns a list. Thus, there is no need to write `return list(x)` as `return x` suffices.

Comment: And, another comment, since `run_parallel` no longer does anything with the `manager` object. It also is not needed. Instead `np.arctan` can be used directly in the `pool.map` call: `x = pool.map(np.arctan, x_array)`. Also, after use, the `pool` should be closed by a call to `pool.close()`or used in a context manager (`with...`) which closes the pool automatically at exit.

Comment: yeah, I didn't refactor the code, just got it working. thanks for your comments, will edit it soon